# How could I know which keyword matches on fulltext search in sunspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I'm using rails + sunspot, and using:

```
Post.search do
    fulltext keywords, minimum_match: 1
end
```

to match the post contain any keyword in the keywords list.

the issue is, I want to know which keyword matches. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when sunspot indexes everything it creates a list of keywords based upon what is in your post model, then i think you can jump into the admin part (there is a url for this), something like

```
http://localhost:8982/solr
```

may not be right, been a while since i used. when in there i think you can check what has been indexed